# How to create in ascii square, triangle, rectangle or circle with C++ and save it to portable bitmap file?

Tags: c++, bitmap, pbm

I don't know how to save in lines 0 and 1 to create a figure. This is my code, which generates lines with zeros. I need to create a square or trianlge, or rectangle (doesn't matter). Just need to know how to do that properly and save to pbm (portable bitmap) as monochromatic image.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream file;

int width=5;
int height=5;
int tab [10][10];

file.open("graphics.pbm");
if(file.good() == true)
{
    file << "P1" << endl;
    file << "# comment" << endl;
    file << "10 10" << endl;

    for (int  i=0; i<width; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<height; j++)
        {
            tab[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for (int  i=0; i<width; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<height; j++)
        {
            file << tab[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }

file.close();
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have some work to do... You need to specify a function for each geometry form which would fill your image.

Here an example which is more C++ like where a class `Image` handle the methods to compute the geometric forms such as `makeFillCircle()`. `Image` class also handles the PBM output. Remark how easy it is now to save it using `std::ostream operator<<` !

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Point { 
    Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {} 
    int x; 
    int y; 
};

struct Image {
    int width;
    int height;
    std::vector<int> data; // your 2D array of pixels in a linear/flatten storage

    Image(size_t w, size_t h) : width(w), height(h), data(w * h, 0) {} // we fill data with 0s

    void makeFillCircle(const Point& p, int radius) {
        // we do not have to test every points (using bounding box)
        for (int i = std::max(0, p.x - radius); i < std::min(width-1, p.x + radius) ; i ++) {
            for (int j = std::max(0,p.y - radius); j < std::min(height-1, p.y + radius); j ++) {
                // test if pixel (i,j) is inside the circle
                if ( (p.x - i) * (p.x - i) + (p.y - j) * (p.y - j) < radius * radius ) {
                    data[i * width + j] = 1;  //If yes set pixel on 1 !
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image& img) {
    os << "P1\n" << img.width << " " << img.height << "\n";
    for (auto el : img.data) { os << el << " "; }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Image img(100,100);
    img.makeFillCircle(Point(60,40), 30); // first big circle
    img.makeFillCircle(Point(20,80), 10); // second big circle
    std::cout << img << std::endl; // the output is the PBM file
}
```

**<kbd>[Live Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/764dd1a959c17245)</kbd>**

Result is :

[image: two circles]

And voilà... I let you the fun to create your own functions `makeRectangle()`, `makeTriangle()` for your needs ! That requires some little maths !

**Edit BONUS**

As asked in the comment, here a little member function which would save the image in a file. Add it in the Image class (you can also if you prefer have a free function outside the class). Since we have a ostream operator<< this is straightforward :

```
void save(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(filename, std::ios::out);
    ofs << (*this);
    ofs.close();
}
```

An other way without modifying the code would be to catch the output of the program in a file with something like this on your terminal :

`./main >> file.pgm`

Comment: Have no idea why debuger in Code Blocks give me errors.
error: ‘el’ does not name a type
error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘return’

Comment: Because you did not include the flag `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`. You should add them :)

Comment: Works great. I'm wondering how to save it as a pbm file to a hard drive.

Comment: @GallAnonim Added at the end my answer a bonus method to do that.

Comment: Tried to save it using this:
file.open("graphics.pbm");
but without success.

Comment: @GallAnonim in your main you should call : `img.save("graphics.pbm");` rather ><

Comment: freopen("output.pbm","w",stdout);
    std::cout << img << std::endl; // the output is the PBM file
    return 0;

Solved the problem :) Big Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: checked this void but gives me errors in debugger. 
In member function ‘void Image::save(const string&)’:
error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Image]’

Comment: @GallAnonim Can you precise how do you call the save function please in your code ?

Comment: freopen is the only way to change the narrow/wide orientation of a stream once it has been established by an I/O operation or by std::fwide.

Solution:
int main() {
    std::cout <<"Draw circles";
    Image img(100,100);
    img.makeFillCircle(Point(60,40), 30); // first big circle
    img.makeFillCircle(Point(20,80), 10); // second big circle
    freopen("image.pbm","w",stdout); // save the stdout to the file
    std::cout << img << std::endl; // the output is the PBM file
    return 0;
}